# Create custom terraform module based on module available in terraform registry

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to create custom module on top of module available in terraform registry ??
main.tf file inside module folder should reference module available in terraform registry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Terraform modules can reference other modules.